# Displaying data from multiple datasets to same scale in R

Tags: r

I have a table that looks like this when read in by read.csv

```
       Count     Rate Thread1 Thread2 Thread3 Thread4 Thread5 Thread6 Thread7
1         672981   38      41      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
2        3617775   36      35      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
3        7129723   37      37      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
4       11072753   37      37      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
5       11256983   16      16      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
6       12264060   33      35      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
7       19821098   38      37      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
8       30912578   38      38      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
9       34943731   38      38      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
10      40564202   38      38      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
11      43784730   37      37      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
12      48346827   38      38      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
13      49575847   34      34      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
14      51078640   35      35      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
15      54806421   38      38      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
16      54951989   34      34       0      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
17      55086821   29      14      14      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
18      55187564   39      19      19      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

(And so on ... the other threads come in as the data builds up)

Apologies for asking such a basic question, but I'd like to display the data from each series on the same scale (ie x = Count, y = Rate). How do I do this?

If I try this:

```
> plot(Rate ~ Count, type="l", pch=20, col=2)
> par(new=T)
> plot(faultrate$Thread1~Count, type="l", pch=20, col=7, axes=F)
```

The x scale matches, but the y scale does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @user1317221_G suggested, you can manually tweak the `ylim` arguments. However, I find `ggplot2` much easier for this kind of plots. You need to take an approach like this (where I assume that you data is in the `dat` data.frame):

```
library(reshape2) 
library(ggplot2)
dat_melt = melt(dat, id.vars = 'Count')
ggplot(dat_melt, aes(x = Count, y = value, color = variable)) + geom_line()
```

This will draw a line in a plot for each `Rate`/`Thread` using a different color, using the same x and y limits. `ggplot2` does this for you, no need to set those manually. If you want to create a plot per `Rate`/`Thread`, not one plot with lines, have a look at `facet_wrap`.

Answer (score 1):

`ylim = c(whatever, whatever)` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to plot many 'Rate' and 'Thread' columns against 'Count' in the same plot, you may check `matplot`:

```
# Select first column (Count) as x variable, and all colums _except_ x as y variable. 

# basic, default matplot
matplot(x = df[ , 1], y = df[ , -1] , type = "l")

# slightly customized matplot
# create a vector of numbers, one for each response variable
# numbers are mapped to colours in plot and legend
cols = seq_len( ncol(df)-1 )

matplot(x = df[, 1], y = df[ , -1] ,
        type = "l",
        lty = 1,
        col = cols)

legend("bottom", 
       legend = names(df[ , -1]), 
       lty = 1,
       col = cols)
```

Or alternatively, reshape your data and use `ggplot`:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
df2 <- melt(df, id.var = "Count")
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = Count, y = value, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line()
```